# How to use functions in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How does one make a function that doesn't auto-trigger on starting the batch file?
I got this code and when I run it, it immediately echo's the text within the function `_verifyWindowsVersion` even though I never called it.

```
@echo Off

echo First line

:: Make sure that the Windows version is compitable.
:_VerifyWindowsVersion
echo Your Windows version of windows is not supported.
Exit
```

It does print the "First line" echo but it also prints the "Your windows version of windows is not supported" echo.

How can I prevent the function from running if I don't call it?

Comment: put a `goto :eof` into the line before.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan  it now works as intended!

Comment: Take a look at the [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)...

Comment: @Stephan - I prefer EXIT /B over GOTO :EOF. They are functionally equivalent, but I think the EXIT /B reads better, especially since the :EOF label does not physically exist.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in `cmd` files tend to follow the structure below, complete with localised scope:

```
:main
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off

    call :outputPi

    call :setTo42 myvar
    echo Should be empty: %localvar%
    echo Should be 42: %myvar%

    endlocal
    goto :eof

:outputPi
    setlocal
    echo 3.14159
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:setTo42
    setlocal
    set localvar=99
    set retval=42
    endlocal&&set %1=%retval%
    goto :eof
```

The two functions are basically one which does something and one which returns a value. They both have `setlocal/endlocal` so that environment changes don't escape, the `setTo42` one uses a nifty trick to specifically *allow* one or more variables to escape.

The trick is that the entire line is interpreted before it starts to execute. That means `retval` have been turned into `42` before the `endlocal` cleans up and, after the cleanup `%1` (the variable for the name you passed in) will be set correctly.

All the `goto :eof` lines literally go to the end of the file where they'll exit the current level. For functions, that means returning to the caller. For the main program, that means exiting, bypassing all the functions as a result.